# Perl: Why this produces Early return

Tags: perl

I found something very confusing

I used to have a method with various instructions that ended up like:

```
    $self->save;
    $object1->save;
    for my $action (@{$self->actions}) {
         $action->save;
     }
    return $self;
```

I changed it to:

```
return if !$self->save;
return if defined $object1 && !$object1->save;
for my $action (@{$self->actions}) {
    return if !$action->save;
}
return $self;
```

The first version runs until the last line. In the second version, I never get to the last line. I have not modified anything else in my whole system. What am i doing wrong?

**Update1:**

Notice

```
    return if !$self->save;            
    return if defined $object1 && !$object1->save;

    for my $action (@{$self->actions}) {
           $action->save;
    }          
    return $self;
```

also finishes early.

**Update2:**

$object1

```
   my $object1 = $self->get_chosen;
```

does the following:

```
 sub get_chosen {
     my ($self) = @_;
     my $chosen_id = $self->_get_chosen_id;
     return undef if !defined $chosen_id;
     my ($chosen)
        = grep { $_->id eq $chosen_id } @{ $self->members };
     return $chosen;
 }
```

Comment: What is the class of `$object1`? What does it do? Can't you sprinkle the code with debugging statements to find out on what object your sub aborts, and what is so special about that object? In a way, your code is equivalent to `return if foo(); return if bar(); $_ and return for baz();` – This can't be debugged in a meaningful way without knowing what `foo`, `bar`, `baz` are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `$action->save`, one of your instances is returning a false value.

Answer (score 0):

For the record.
I still dont know why the code section 2 had an early return but if I change

```
  return if defined $object1 && !$object1->save;
```

for

```
  return if ($object1 && !$object1->save);
```

the early return bug is gone.